# Google Cloud - Unable to SSH to new instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a new Google Cloud business account.  Then created a new VM instance.

When I attempt to SSH using the web console, I the pop up window has an error:

You cannot connect to the VM instance because of an unexpected error.  Wait a few moments then try again.

[image]

Then about 1 second later, the error screen flips to this:

Code: 1006 Please ensure you can make a proper https connection to the IAP for TCP hostname: https://tunnel.cloudproxy.app You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

[image]

---

I have checked firewall rules, and there is an all-ip ingress rule for port 22.

I can connect to the instance using the gcloud console.

I've deleted the instance and recreated it, and the behavior is the same.

I'm at a loss about how to proceed here.

---

What I've tried so far based on suggestions below:

1. Add an ingress firewall rule with the IAP IP address (there is already a firewall rule allowing port 22 traffic from all IP addresses, so I didn't think this would make a difference - but I tried anyway) - this did not make a difference.
2. Adjust the ingress firewall rule with the IAP IP address to allow all ports.  This still doesn't work.
3. Added IAP TCP Forwarding per https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#grant-permission .  This continues to fail the same way
4. I've gone into the IAP configuration for the instance and confirmed that the principal I am connecting with is listed as an IAP Secured Tunnel user.  Note that I'm using the GC account admin as the user.

Note that this entire Google Cloud account was created solely for this project - so this is a brand new, plain vanilla account and instance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I know the answer to your difficulties, but, for clarificaton sake, are you behind any sort of Proxy? I ran into problems connecting to Google Cloud behind a proxy in the past.

One thing you can try for debug purposes to see if it has to do with your specific network setups is SSH in via an online Dev service such as Amazon AWS Cloud9.

Sorry if this is not helpful, but I saw the question and figured I would at least see if I could help.

Comment: My workstation is not behind a proxy.  I'm able to do the web SSH to other Google Cloud instances (on a different GC account) with no problems.  So definitely not a problem with local networking/access...  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the error message you are getting, the `error 1006` appears in the GCP Console UI after 1 hour of inactivity of the SSH session via IAP with VMs using the Internal IP, and this is a session timeout on the Google side.

You can allow IAP to connect to your VM instance by creating a firewall rule that will apply to all the VM instances that you want to be accessible using IAP. create an ingress traffic from the
IP range `35.235.240.0/20`. This range will contain all the IP addresses that the IAP uses for TCP forwarding. As you have mention from your firewall rules that their is port 22 for SSH as this is also a requirement to allow connection for SSH.

You can also follow the steps below to allow SSH access on your VM instances:

1. Open the Firewall Rules page.
2. On the Firewall Rules page, click Create firewall rule.
3. Configure the following settings:

```
Name: allow-ingress-from-iap
Direction of traffic: Ingress
Target: All instances in the network
Source filter: IP ranges
Source IP ranges: 35.235.240.0/20
Protocols and ports: Select TCP and enter 22 to allow SSH.
```

4. Click Create.

You can also check you IAM to grant permission to use IAP TCP forwarding.
it is recommended granting the following roles for trusted administrators:

`roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` (project or VM)

`roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1` (project)

for complete reference you can check this documentation on [IAP for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#preparing_your_project_for_tcp_forwarding) and [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).

Comment: The failure is happening before any connection is established - definitely not after an hour...  There is already a firewall rule allowing all port 22 traffic (so I doubt that adding another rule with the specific IP address would make a difference  - but I tried it anyway, with no luck)

Comment: I added the tunnelResourceAccessor and instanceAdmin.v1 roles, and still have the same failure.

Comment: have you tried to create a new instance on other region besides from the region that you are usually creating? and after creating does it show the same error message?

Comment: I created another instance in the same region (us-west) and it still failed.  This is super basic stuff - brand new account, just trying to set up a free micro instance to start testing some things out for a new startup.  Do you think the region could actually make a difference?  I just tried setting up an instance running under a Google Web personal account (us-west region), and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: You can try to make on other region just to compare the behavior, are you also the owner of the Google Cloud Platform business account?

Comment: Yes - I am the owner on the account - I literally set up the Google Cloud business account a day ago for this specific purpose.

Comment: Run this command from your Cloud Shell and share the output.

`gcloud compute ssh VM_NAME --troubleshoot --tunnel-through-iap`


Another question is did you managed to check SSH using web console from different browser?

Comment: Unfortunately, I ran out of time for this work and just threw the entire account away and started clean with a personal account.  Once I did that, I had the new instance up and running in less than 5 minutes.  I'm sure this is something related to the business account setup...  Thank you for your help, and sorry we ran out of time.